# Connecting transistors in series

Tags: transistors

I know we can connect two or more transistors in parallel to increasing the maximum switching current, but what about increasing the maximum voltage?

Can we connect them in series?

For example, connecting two 2N3055 to give 100V 5A rather than 50V 5A?

Comment: Why not mosfets rated for higher voltage?

Comment: Avoid this at all costs! This is from someone who makes a living out of having to series connect transistors to get enough voltage rating. At 100 V, this isn't evena question. Get a propper 100 V transistor!

Comment: @winny, in what applications do you use series mosfets?

Comment: High voltage...

Comment: Obviously. How high?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Do you have AoE3?  See figure 9.111  (Also shows bjt's in series.)

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Very high, from kV to a few hundred kV! Going from one transistor to two is a monumental increase in complexity, losses and special cases to consider. Just don't!

Comment: Never meant to, my systems are well limited within 600V

Comment: @GregoryKronblum You are living the easy path in life. :-) Enjoy it!

Comment: BTW, 2N3055 in the 1970s was called an "industry dumping ground," meaning that transistors that couldn't pass tests for other part numbers were marked and sold as 2N3055s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes that is possible but less trivial than placing them in parallel.

What you need is **cascoding** which is done like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNEcAC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Qsw does the actual switching

Qcasc is for dividing the voltage between the transistors

I have used this kind of circuits where I need to switch 5.5 V but are limited to using (on-chip) transistors which can only withstand 2.7 V.

Comment: That looks like logic gates.

Answer (score 11):

A cascode amplifier is a kind of series connection where a common emitter stage drives a common base stage.  Wikipedia shows a variant with multiple common base stages:[image]

Comment: If R5 connects to the output collector of T5 it can get better performance.  As shown the output can only go down to ~750V when T5 saturates.  The increased base current will pull the voltage at T5 base down but T5 being in saturation can cause slow response when the signal has to rise again.  This type of circuit was often used for video amplifiers where the pulse response was important.

Comment: One of the important applications of the cascode connection is to compensate for the Miller Effect capacitance.  If the collector voltage is more or less constant, the collector-base capacitance doesn't matter as much.  In the good old days, tetrode and pentode vacuum tubes served the same purpose.

Comment: Agreed, but not in this circuit as both the base and collector are changing.  If the transistor goes into saturation charge storage in the collector region can make it take a very long time to recover.

Comment: Editor doesn't like "cascode" and overrules me when I use the word, "correcting" it to "cascade." I have to insist on my spelling to get what I want. I hate spell checkers that do more than warn.

Answer (score 0):

> can we connect them in series?

yes.

> for example connecting two 2N3055 for gave 100V 5A rather than 50V 5A?

Yes, if the switching voltage is also correspondingly increased.

Otherwise, the top transistor takes most of the voltage drop.

Such devices do / did exist. Google emitter-switched transistors. ST made some.